# Converting Global Coordinates to Character Local Coordinates and Back

Tags: algorithm, coordinates

I am trying to implement obstacle avoidance behavior from the paper steering behaviours for autonomous agents. What I am stuck at is how do i convert global coordinates (2d) to local coordinates for my character?

Basically Say I am at 1,0 and the enemy is 10,0. I would like to move the origin to 1,0 so I get 9,0 as the enemy coordinates.

What I ended up doing,

to translate to local,

```
[1 0 -tx]   [x]
[0 1 -ty] x [y]
[0 0  1]    [1]
```

then back to global using,

```
[1 0 tx]   [x]
[0 1 ty] x [y]
[0 0 1]    [1]
```

tx,ty is the local char coords and x,y is the enemy char coords.

Comment: is this a "what is a mathematical operator that gets 1 and 10 and returns 9" question, really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract the points.

Relative = Position - moved axis point.

(10,0) - (1,0) = (9,0)

[**Displacement**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_%28vector%29)

**Edit:**

Using an [Affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) to convert the entire x,y plane:

Just for numeric issues, lets choose another perspective point: (3,7)

```
[x] = [ 1 0 -3 ] = [x`] = x -3
[y]   [ 0 1 -7 ] = [y`] = y -7
[1]   [ 0 0 1  ] = [1 ] = we don't care
```

**[Transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)**

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, It does not work. AFAIK I am supposed to multiply coords with a transformation matrix but I don't know to build that matrix.

Comment: You want to make a transformation for the entire set of coordinates so you could look at it from a new axis point ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to convert all obstacle coordinates (in global space) to local character coordinates.

Comment: Basically you want an **Affine transformation** ... How to implement that, it depends on the graphics SDK you're using. Basically it's just adding a dimension to the matrix so you can add constants. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Comment: @Hamza : I've edited with an example for an affine transformation matrix

Comment: I have edited the question explained what I have come up with. Is that the right implementation?